# Sqoop concatenate column values based on row key

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I'm using sqoop to export data from MySQL to HBase. I have specified a primary row key. Since the primary row key should be unique;  for each primary key, I would like concatenate the values of multiple row values for that primary key in the same HBase row but separate them using a delimiter.

How can I do this? I searched around and was not ale to find anything on the net. Maybe I did not query the right way

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it from the SQL side ? Using the concat function of MsSQL like  the folowing

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1,'|',field2,'|',field3) AS MyHbasekey FROM myTable;
```

Maybe I've misunderstood so feel free to provide an example.